# How i can set Specific package (app) for app action

Tags: android, apk, smali, apktool

hello there is an app to add stickers to whatsapp.

and there is 3 version of whatsapp with Different packages name

```
com.whatsapp
com.gbwhatsapp
com.gbwhatsapp3
```

and i want my app stickers to add stickers only to com.gbwhatsapp and i don't want to see complite action with message

i trid to change action and many things but the app get crash

the action to add stickers is :

```
com.whatsapp.intent.action.ENABLE_STICKER_PACK
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldolD.png)

and the code in stickers app is

```
new-instance v0, Landroid/content/Intent;

invoke-direct {v0}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>()V

const-string v1, "com.whatsapp.intent.action.ENABLE_STICKER_PACK"

invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/content/Intent;->setAction(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;
```

can i add code after this to Specific app package to com.gbwhatsapp for this action?

i am using apktool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a call to [`Intent.setPackage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage(java.lang.String). e.g.

```
const-string v1, "com.gbwhatsapp"
invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/content/Intent;->setPackage(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;
```